# How should I call "summer prepared" for a car?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

When a car has been made ready for summer, there is a word for it, at least in Dutch: the car is "zomerklaar". In case of winter it is called "winterklaar". Is there a word for it in English? A word that means "prepared for summer" in the case of cars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summerize** and **winterize**.  But hardly anybody does that anymore, at least where I live.

Comment: Yeah, when I lived in New York we did *winterize* things. But even now that I live in Arizona we never summer-ize anything.  Summer just doesn’t require special treatment like winter does.

Comment: It may require the removal of the snow tires, if you still use them.  If not, the tire pressure may need to be adjusted. Also, some people use a different weight of oil in the summer.

Answer (score 0):

In winter, we call it "winterized" or "winterizing", but we don't have a reverse for summer.  Or if we do, I've never heard it in the US midwest.

I believe most tune-ups for vehicles are implicit that they're done in summer, or done as routine maintenance, and it's only for winter that you need to put your snow tires on, and make sure your antifreeze is good and your windshield fluid won't freeze in winter.

Answer (score 0):

"Winterized" is a common word in AmE, often used to describe preparing a house or car for winter.  But I've never heard its logical opposite, "summerized."  An advertiser would most likely use a phrase like "get ready for summer," or entice you to "beat the heat" by purchasing their products or services.

The fact that "summerize" is not in common usage probably has something to do with the fact that it would be a confusing homonym for the common word "summarize."  The lack of any common antonym for "winterize" may also reflect the attitude that, although winter is threatening, summer requires no special preparation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the verb "summerize" in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/summerize), meaning to prepare something for summer weather.  A car made thus ready has been "summarized."

No, wait a minute.  *I've* summarized the description of a *summerized* car. (Thanks to StoneyB.)

Comment: It's very useful, a summarized car. You can fold it up and put it in your pocket and don't have to worry about parking. :)